# Removing the padding from twitter bootstrap design

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Am using [this design](http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/shop-homepage/) in my project. Am not good in CSS, the problem am facing now is removing the empty area that is below the navbar and stick the picture (800x300) in the navbar.

Where show i check inside the bootstrap CSS design?

Answer (score 0):

This padding si normally inside

```
.wrap > .container {
    padding: 100px 15px 10px;  /* the first one si for top padding */
}
```

or

```
.container {
    padding: 100px 15px 10px;  /* the first one si for top padding */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way to achieve this, since removing the padding from the navbar does not change anything because of its stack level, is adding to the container div `<div class="container">` below the navbar the styling properties: `style="position: relative; top: -20px;"` in the HTML document.

Mind that if you want to have more control to it you should add a class to it, like `<div class="container moveUp">`and on your style.css file customize it like this: `.moveUp{ position: relative; top:-20px; }`

Answer (score 0):

That would be in Bootstrap CSS documentation.
Check here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/